# Adding-deleting jQuery tabs from javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am a newcomer to jQuery and I need further insight on a topic which got me stuck for a while.
I am developing an application where the GUI frontend is generated using HTML5 + Javascript and I need to process a string (coming from the user) and modify the tabs and the number of them on the fly. (Even create and destroy tabs on the fly).

The code for the tabs is picked from [JQueryUI](http://jqueryui.com/tabs/#manipulation):

```
 <script>
$(function() {
var tabTitle = $( "#tab_title" ),
tabContent = $( "#tab_content" ),
tabTemplate = "<li><a href='#{href}'>#{label}</a> <span class='ui-icon ui-icon-close' role='presentation'>Remove Tab</span></li>",
tabCounter = 2;

var tabs = $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
// modal dialog init: custom buttons and a "close" callback resetting the form inside
var dialog = $( "#dialog" ).dialog(
{
    autoOpen: false,
    modal: true,
    buttons: {
    Add: function() 
    {
    addTab();
    $( this ).dialog( "close" );
    },
    Cancel: function() 
    {
        $( this ).dialog( "close" );
    }
    },
    close: function() {
    form[ 0 ].reset();
    }
}
);

// addTab form: calls addTab function on submit and closes the dialog
var form = dialog.find( "form" ).submit(function( event ) 
{
    addTab();
    dialog.dialog( "close" );
    event.preventDefault();
});

// actual addTab function: adds new tab using the input from the form above
function addTab() 
{
    var label = tabTitle.val() || "Tab " + tabCounter,
    id = "tabs-" + tabCounter,
    li = $( tabTemplate.replace( /#\{href\}/g, "#" + id ).replace( /#\{label\}/g, label ) ),
    tabContentHtml = tabContent.val() || "Tab " + tabCounter + " content.";
    tabs.find( ".ui-tabs-nav" ).append( li );
    tabs.append( "<div id='" + id + "'><p>" + tabContentHtml + "</p></div>" );
    tabs.tabs( "refresh" );
    tabCounter++;
}
// addTab button: just opens the dialog
$( "#add_tab" ).button().click(function() {dialog.dialog( "open" );});

// close icon: removing the tab on click
tabs.delegate( "span.ui-icon-close", "click", function() {var panelId = $( this ).closest( "li" ).remove().attr( "aria-controls" );
$( "#" + panelId ).remove();
tabs.tabs( "refresh" );});

});

function test()
{
/* 
    TODO: Generate the tab title and content and update the GUI with the new tab, generated
            only by writing it in the code.

*/
}
</script>
```

I have been working a lot on this issue but I cannot find a way to add the tab from the function test() defined on my script. How can I access the functionality, which is provided on the original code?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just add this function to your code.

```
function anotherTab(title, content) {
  var label = title || "Tab " + tabCounter,
    id = "tabs-" + tabCounter,
    li = $( tabTemplate.replace( /#\{href\}/g, "#" + id ).replace( /#\{label\}/g, label ) ),
    tabContentHtml = content || "Tab " + tabCounter + " content.";
  tabs.find( ".ui-tabs-nav" ).append( li );
  tabs.append( "<div id='" + id + "'><p>" + tabContentHtml + "</p></div>" );
  tabs.tabs( "refresh" );
  tabCounter++;
}
```

Now if you need a new tab instantly - you put `anotherTab('Tab Name', 'Some content here.');` in your `test` function - BUT you need to put ALL your code in the same context to make it work together - do it like this:

```
<script>
  $(function() {
    // ORIGINAL CODE YOU'VE COPIED FROM JQUERY....
    // ...AND AFTER IT BUT BEFORE '});'

    // 'anotherTab' function code...

    function test() {
      anotherTab('NEW TAB', 'NEW CONTENT');
    }

    test();
  });
</script>
```

**EDIT**.
Ok - so if you need a global scope - the code would be something like this below:

```
<script>
    // global mytabs object containing all data and methods related to our tabs
    var mytabs = {
        tabTemplate: "<li><a href='#{href}'>#{label}</a> <span class='ui-icon ui-icon-close' role='presentation'>Remove Tab</span></li>",
        tabCounter: 2,
        tabs: '',
        init: function(){
            // make tabs with jQuery
            this.tabs = $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
            // handle close-tab icons click event
            this.tabs.delegate( "span.ui-icon-close", "click", function() {
                var panelId = $( this ).closest( "li" ).remove().attr( "aria-controls" );
                $( "#" + panelId ).remove();
                mytabs.tabs.tabs( "refresh" );
            });
        },
        addNewTab: function(title, content){
            var label = title || "Tab " + this.tabCounter,
                id = "tabs-" + this.tabCounter,
                li = $( this.tabTemplate.replace( /#\{href\}/g, "#" + id ).replace( /#\{label\}/g, label ) ),
                tabContentHtml = content || "Tab " + this.tabCounter + " content.";
            this.tabs.find( ".ui-tabs-nav" ).append( li );
            this.tabs.append( "<div id='" + id + "'><p>" + tabContentHtml + "</p></div>" );
            this.tabs.tabs( "refresh" );
            this.tabCounter++;
        }
    }

    // when document is ready initiate tabs
    $(function() {
        mytabs.init();
    }

    // your test function
    function test() {
        // just use a method defined in mytabs
        mytabs.addNewTab( 'Added Tab', 'Some content...' );
    }
</script>
```

Comment: I appreciate your answer really much!, would it be possible to access this context (I guess $(function() {}) from another function which I need to be available globally?. It's because I need to call that function from a C++ backend... =/

Comment: What I've posted was just the quickest solution to your code - but it's really easy to take all that code outside into the global scope. I'll show you how in an edit to my answer.